# Multiple stage routing in customer Symfony2 framework

Tags: php, symfony

What I would like to do is separate the `/{id}` into it's own routing table, so if it's omitted, I can set a default id and use the same routing table.

index.php:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$routes = new RouteCollection();
$routes->add('month_view', new Route('/{id}/month/{year}/{month}',
                    array('_controller' => function(Request $request) {
                            $id = $request->get('id'
                            $year = $request->get('year');
                            $month = $request->get('month');
                            return MonthController::showAction($id, $year, $month);
                            })));
$routes->add('day_view', new Route('/{id}/day/{year}/{month}/{day}',
                    array('_controller' => function(Request $request) {
                            $id = $request->get('id');
                            $year = $request->get('year');
                            $month = $request->get('month');
                            $day = $request->get('day');
                            return DayController::showAction($id, $year, $month, $day);
                            })));
$framework = new Framework($routes);
$framework->handle(Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
```

Framework.php:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;

class Framework extends HttpKernel\HttpKernel
{
    public function __construct($routes)
    {
            $context = new RequestContext();
            $matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $context);
            $resolver = new HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver();

            $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
            $dispatcher->addSubscriber(new HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener($matcher));
            $dispatcher->addSubscriber(new HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener('UTF-8'));

            parent::__construct($dispatcher, $resolver);
    }
}
```

This is for a project that uses Symfony2 components but not the entire Symfony2 framework.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider 3 options:

1.

Simpliest solution would be to use a keyword as an id, so an url could look like
`/default/month/2015/12`
then you would recognize the fact that `$id == 'default'` in your `showAction`  and use some default id to show data

2.

Same as 1. but instead of checking if `$id == 'default'` in your `showAction`, you would create `showDefaultAction` for an url 
`/month/{year}/{month}` (no id parameter)

3.

again based on 1. but you would add 2 routes: `/{id}/month/{year}/{month}` one would require $id to be an integer, the other one would expect a string(the 'default' option), you could then lead them to two different actions (show/showDefault)